# How do I select value in next row everytime when the stored procedure is run in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a simple table with 4 text like below,

```
UK, France, USA, Germany
```

And then I want to write a script to select "UK" when my stored procedure runs for 1st time. After sometime (may be in few seconds or next day) when the stored procedure run again it has to select "France" and when the stored procedure is run for the 5th time than it has to pic "UK" again, looping through this 4 text.

I am new to SQL so please be bit elaborate or use official sql terms which I can google and learn. Thank you.

Comment: You need to save state of the execution, consider creating another table and save your execution count of the stored procedure inside it, inside your stored procedure you get value from the table to filter your data then update back the ++counter to the table.

Comment: Glad it  helped.